# Flutter -Adding a popup menu button to the icon in the BottomNavigationBar

Tags: ios, flutter, dart

I want when I press the camera button, a list of three options every option lead for the different page appears
It looks like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ry2sY.png)
so I want when the user clicks on the camera icon, he does not go to the upload page directly, but rather a list of three options appears for him, each option goes to a different page
like this [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HqXxx.jpg)

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:fluttershare/services/auth.dart';
import 'package:fluttershare/pages/activity_feed.dart';
import 'package:fluttershare/pages/profile.dart';
import 'package:fluttershare/pages/search.dart';
import 'package:fluttershare/pages/timeline.dart';
import 'package:fluttershare/pages/upload.dart';

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
   final key = GlobalKey<State<BottomNavigationBar>>();
  AuthBase authBase = AuthBase();
  bool isAuth = false;
  PageController pageController;
  int pageIndex = 0;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    pageController = PageController();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    pageController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  onPageChanged(int pageIndex) {
    setState(() {
      this.pageIndex = pageIndex;
    });
  }

  onTap(int pageIndex) {
    pageController.animateToPage(
      pageIndex,
      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 200),
      curve: Curves.easeInOut,
    );
  }


  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      //appBar: AppBar(
      //  title: Text('style me'),
      // ),
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: PageView(
        //colors:Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
        children: <Widget>[
          Timeline(),
          ActivityFeed(),
          Upload(),
          Search(),
          Profile(),
          

        ],
        controller: pageController,
        onPageChanged: onPageChanged,
        physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: CupertinoTabBar(
          currentIndex: pageIndex,
          onTap: onTap,
          activeColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
          items: [
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.whatshot),
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.notifications_active),
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
  
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.photo_camera,
                size: 35.0,
                
              ),
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.search),
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.account_circle),
            ),
          ]
             

          
          
      ),
   
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to change `CupertinoTabBar`'s `onTap` method to look something like this:

```
  onTap(int pageIndex) {
    if (pageIndex != 2){
     /// If the pressed page is not the camera, animates to the page
     /// The camera page is on index number 2
     pageController.animateToPage(
      pageIndex,
      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 200),
      curve: Curves.easeInOut,
     );
    }
  }
```

After that, in your camera icon `BottomNavigationBarItem` do this:

```
...
/// Wrap the BottomNavigationBar's icon in a GestureDetector    
BottomNavigationBarItem(
      icon: GestureDetector(onTapDown: (TapDownDetails 
       tapDownDetails)=>onTapDown(context, tapDownDetails,),
      child: Icon(
       Icons.photo_camera,
       size: 35.0,      
      ),
     ),),
     
...
```

Add the `onTapDown` function to show the menu:

```
void onTapDown(
    BuildContext context,
    TapDownDetails tapDownDetailsDetails,
  ) {
    final double pressX = tapDownDetailsDetails.globalPosition.dx,
        pressY = tapDownDetailsDetails.globalPosition.dy;

    showMenu(
      context: context,
      position: RelativeRect.fromLTRB(pressX, pressY, pressX, pressY),
      items: getMenuItems(),
    ).then(
      (value) => perfomSelectedAction(context, value),
    );
  }
```

Add this function that returns the items for the menu:

```
  List<PopupMenuEntry<dynamic>> getMenuItems() => [
        PopupMenuItem(value: 'option 1', child: Text('option 1')),
        PopupMenuItem(value: 'option 2', child: Text('option 2')),
        PopupMenuItem(value: 'option 3', child: Text('option 3'))
      ];
```

And finally add the function that handles choosing an option:

```
  Future<dynamic> perfomSelectedAction(dynamic value) {
    switch (value) {
      case 'option 1':
        print('option 1');
        break;
      case 'option 2':
        print('option 2');
        break;
      case 'option 3':
        print('option 3');
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }

    return null;
  }
```

Comment: Thank you it works. You really helped me.

Comment: I'm glad it helped you!